Recursive types in Python and difficulties inferring the type of `type(x)(...)`
Trying to build recursive types to annotate a nested data structure, I hit the following.
This code is correct according to mypy:
IntType = int | list["IntType"] | tuple["IntType", ...]
StrType = str | list["StrType"] | tuple["StrType", ...]


def int2str(x: IntType) -> StrType:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return list(int2str(v) for v in x)
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        return tuple(int2str(v) for v in x)
    return str(x)

But not this one, which should be equivalent:
IntType = int | list["IntType"] | tuple["IntType", ...]
StrType = str | list["StrType"] | tuple["StrType", ...]

def bad_int2str(x: IntType) -> StrType:
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        return type(x)(bad_int2str(v) for v in x)  # error here
    return str(x)

The error message is
line 6: error: Incompatible return value type (
    got "list[int | list[IntType] | tuple[IntType, ...]] | tuple[int | list[IntType] | tuple[IntType, ...], ...]", 
    expected "str | list[StrType] | tuple[StrType, ...]"
)  [return-value]
line 6: error: Generator has incompatible item type 
    "str | list[StrType] | tuple[StrType, ...]"; 
    expected "int | list[IntType] | tuple[IntType, ...]"  [misc]

I would assume mypy could infer that type(x) is either list or tuple.
Is this a limitation of mypy or is there something fishy with this code?
If so, where does the limitation come from?

There's no type erasure for type(x).
What should mypy say about the following?
x: list[int] = [1]
reveal_type(type(x))

If we ask, it says:

Revealed type is "type[builtins.list[builtins.int]]"

So, when you ask for type(x)(some_strtype_iterator), it rightfully complains that you try to construct a list[StrType] | tuple[StrType, ...] from an iterable of IntType.
Both errors hint about that fact: mypy thinks that you return a list or tuple of IntType, because the error inside the expression does not make it lose an already known type. And it also points out that you can't build a list/tuple of IntType from a generator yielding StrType - you didn't intend to build IntType sequence, but type(x) mandates that.
I just started a discussion on the typing forum to clarify the reasons for not erasing the generics for type(x).

Interesting. It makes sense in hindsight. Are there more "conflicts" like this between static type checking and runtime behavior documented somewhere?

@Winks In this case, the behaviour is implementation-dependent. Pytype, for example, passes your bad_int2str(). Similar cases can be found in various discussions like GitHub issues, but there is not yet a comprehensive documentation (not even the specs).

Mypy is a static type checker, which means it does not evaluate type(x)(bad_int2str(v) for v in x) when it runs. So there's no way Mypy knows the type of the expression is the StrType, under the current limitation of the implementation. (Mypy thinks the type of the expression is list[IntType] | tuple[IntType, ...]. See Limitations.)
You can give a hint on type(x) like the following examples.
def good_int2str(x: IntType) -> StrType:
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        ty: type[list | tuple] = type(x)
        return ty(good_int2str(v) for v in x)
    return str(x)

def another_good_int2str(x: IntType) -> StrType:
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        return cast(type[list | tuple], type(x))(
            another_good_int2str(v) for v in x)
    return str(x)


"[...] there's no way Mypy knows the type of the expression is the StrType": Incorrect; it does know (reveal_type(bad_int2str(v) for v in x) shows Generator[<StrType>, None, None]), which is why it raised the "generator has incompatible item type" error in the first place.

No my description is not incorrect. Mypy infers the correct type of the generator argument, but not for the entire constructor call expression.

It knows that, too (list[<IntType>] | tuple[<IntType>, ...], albeit not as OP expected, STerliakov explained why), hence the "incompatible return value type" error.

No, it's not. Check what reference says - "Mypy’s analysis is limited to individual symbols and it will not track relationships between symbols".

I don't think that has anything to do with the matter at hand. You will need to be more explicit: What "individual symbols" and what "relationships" are Mypy not tracking?

I mean Mypy cannot deduce the net result of c(a) is StrType, when the type of a is Generator[StrType, None, None] and the type of c is type[list[<IntType>]] | type[tuple[<IntType>, ...]]. There are two symbols involved in this example, a and c.

...which leads us back to STerliakov's answer, and no, the Limitations section isn't about the relationship between callers and callees like your a and c. That Mypy fails to output the result by OP does not mean "there's no way" for it to know. If it hadn't, the type would have been Any.
